# Java Scanner and errors

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, identifier

Hi I'm trying to make a program that declares a set of strings and a set of ints. After that I want to print both to the console based on the number that I have written.

For example, if I have declared something like this,

```
String a[] = a1 a2 a3 a4 a5

int b[] = 10 20 30 40 50
```

I want to get a1 and 10 printed out if I type in 1 to the scanner.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class value {

    private static Scanner sc;
    public static void main(String args[]){

      String a[] = {"a1","a2","a3","a4","a5"};
      int b[] = {100, 220, 200, 230, 500};

      sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("type in a number");
      String input = sc.nextLine();

      int i = Integer.parseInt(input);
      int j = i - 1;

      System.out.println(a[j] + b[j]);
    }
  }
```

could you tell me what is wrong about this? Im really new to programming

Comment: you are vulnerable on parsing a string. if string doesn't have any integer type then type parsing exception will surely come.So handle it.

Comment: Can you specify what problem exactly you're experiencing? It will be easier for others to help you.

Comment: @pnt- you removed the } from the question. now it will work fine. If you have the answer you should give the answer, do not edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is assuming your `int[]` and `String[]` arrays have already been declared.**

First of all, setup your Scanner and read the input.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();
```

After this, try to parse the input from a String to an Integer, which will let you grab data from the arrays.

```
int j = 0;
try {
    j = Integer.parseInt(input);
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("NaN");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Now you have a number. All you have to do now, is try to grab data from the array.

```
try {
    System.out.println(a[j] + " " + b[j]);
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("Index out of range!");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

We catch `Exception`'s incase of failure. The first case, is if the input is not a number. The second being if the `length` of the array is less than the requested index.

You also have to make sure you are following the standard that the **first** index of an array is **0**, not **1**.

**Example with your code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Value {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String a[] = {"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"};
        int b[] = {100, 220, 200, 230, 500};

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type in a number.");
        String input = sc.nextLine();

        int i;
        try {
            i = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("NaN");
            System.exit(-1); // Replace with whatever you want if it fails.
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(a[i] + " " + b[i]);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Index out of range: " + i);
            System.exit(-1); // Again, change to whatever you want.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: other than exception handling, what's the difference with the author's code?

Comment: @pnt Nothing. The point of the author's question, is what's **wrong** with their code. The only problem is error handling is non-existent. As **Yogesh Seralia** commented on the question, there are parsing vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks! Problem Solved!

Comment: @AllanKim No problem! If I answered your questions correctly, please consider marking it as the correct answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Value {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] a = {"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"};
        int[] b = {100, 220, 200, 230, 500};

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            if (choice < 0 || choice > Math.min(a.length, b.length)) {
                System.out.println("out of range...");
            } else {
                System.out.println(a[choice] + "\t" + b[choice]);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

When you type 0, it will print out `a1 100`,type 1,print out `a2 220`.

Comment: Where is `choice` defined?

Comment: seems like you invented `choice` out of thin air

Comment: before if statement，`Integer choice = scanner.nextInt();`

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is , the `System.out.println(a[j] + b[j]);`
 out of main() method. It should be in main() and remove `}` after `int j = i - 1;` (it is an extra bracket)

In your code:

.
.
.

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(input);
int j = i - 1;
  }

  System.out.println(a[j] + b[j]);
}}
```

the right code:

....

```
            int i = Integer.parseInt(input);
    int j = i - 1;
    System.out.println(a[j] + b[j]);
}}
```

Also you can add Exception handler to handle like "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException".